# setting up Android SDK - get the "Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml" error no matter what

Tags: android, connection, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android SDK Manager gives “Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml” error when selecting repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808167/android-sdk-manager-gives-failed-to-fetch-url-https-dl-ssl-google-com-android)

In trying to set up the Android SDK, I can't seem to get connected to the repository. With the proxy set correctly, and https forced to http, I get this error:

**Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: Connection reset**.

Without the proxy set, I get the same result, except it says the connection has timed out.

Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with your proxy settings. I was getting that error until i set my proxy correctly. 
Also you should be using Https not Http when you have the proxy setup.