# Android SDK DownLoad Failed

Tags: android

I'm trying to install a platform but when I open Android Manager then I click Available Software then select the https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml repository

I get this error:

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

I have also tried downloading by clicking on force "http:" for all "https:" downloads on settings panel but it still doesn't help.

I'm working on Windows 7(x64).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is an exact duplicate of [setting up Android SDK - get the "Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml" error no matter what](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918473/setting-up-android-sdk-get-the-failed-to-fetch-url-http-dl-ssl-google-com-a). At least make an effort to search before asking a question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please deactivate any firewall, and any virus protection software. I tried every thing, but this is the final solution. When doing that every thing goes fine, I was able to finish my android sdk downloads.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this

> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Use this

> http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Also check if you are using any proxy.