# 3.2 sdk platform install problem. "Done. Nothing was installed"

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, installation

I select everything in the new 3.2 update but then I get the error message "done. nothing was installed" after the sdk manager runs its process.

Here is the sdk install log:

```
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 12
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r12-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 6
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\platform-tools_r06-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 13, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\docs-3.2_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-3.2_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Android Compatibility package, revision 3
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\compatibility_r03.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google Admob Ads Sdk package, revision 3
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\googleadmobadssdkandroid-4.1.1.zip (Access is denied)
Skipping 'SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1'; it depends on 'Android SDK Tools, revision 12' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 13, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1' which was not installed.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK Manager Not Installing Components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Start the SDK manager as Administrator.

---

- Right Click `SDK Manager`
- Select `Run As Administrator`
- Click the `YES` button

Comment: thank you, never thought the permissions issue could be the problem

Comment: Running SDK manager as root from my Mac's terminal solved the issue.

Answer (score 9):

The key to your problem is simple. You need to have an administrator access. The files are not being created automatically and hence the installation fails.

`Start>>And roid SDK Manager>>right click SDK Manager` and select run as an administrator.

Try downloading again. It should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

these answers are all for windows users since it recommends running the manager as an administrator. for those on any linux platform (I'm on OSX), I suggest you cd into the folder where the sdk is trying to download (for me it was /android-sdk/temp)

then I allowed all permissions in the folder recursively by running

```
sudo chmod 777 ./
```

Comment: Is 777 perms really required? Seems a bit dangerous.

Comment: I guess you could set the permissions back to what they were if you feel unsafe with the permissions kept at 777

Answer (score 2):

As you will likely be using the SDK Manager more than once, and it will always need these admin rights, a better option than having to remember to right-click on the file/shortcut and select 'run as administrator' every time would be to set the application to always be executed with admin rights without you having to remember to do this every time by doing the following:

1. Navigate to the SDK Manager.
2. Right-click on the SDK Manager.exe file.
3. Select properties from the context menu.
4. Click the compatibility tab.
5. Select the "Run this program as an administrator" checkbox.
6. Click the ok button to close the properties dialog.

You can find more detailed information about this and related options [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, simply run `gksudo android` or `kdesudo android` to start the Android SDK manager as root.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and this is what i did
in windows 10 the SDK manager is located at

```
C:\Users\your_userfolder\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

if you can't see the "Appdata" folder just click on "view" tab at the top of the window and check the "Hidden items folder".
right click on the "SDK Manager.exe" file and click on "run as administrator". 
After that the packages should start to install