# Unable to install Android 2.3.3 SDK Platform

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [3.2 sdk platform install problem. “Done. Nothing was installed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783981/3-2-sdk-platform-install-problem-done-nothing-was-installed)

I'm trying to install SDK Platform for Android 2.3.3 via SDK manager but when I press the install button I get the following error message:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783981/3-2-sdk-platform-install-problem-done-nothing-was-installed/6784009#6784009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting Acess denied. so i think try running your SDK manager as Administrator.

Right click SDK Manager and click Run as Administrator