# Android Studio update SDK - Done. Nothing was installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-tools

Hi guys I have the same problem of this question: [3.2 sdk platform install problem. "Done. Nothing was installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783981/3-2-sdk-platform-install-problem-done-nothing-was-installed)

But all similar problems have been solved with -> right click / Run as Administrator. Well when I try to do this, Windows keep me a cmd window that said:

"Failed to execute tools\android.bat:, error 2
Impossible find that file"

and a popup window with the same message

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys I solved going into path of SDK and double click on android.bat file that SDK Manager didn't find.

Answer (score 7):

You need to run the SDK Manager as a Administrator, the problem was is it is failing to create an folder due to lack of permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can see `File`-`Project Structure`-`SDK Location`, check `Android SDK Location`, set it to directory of your SDK.

Comment: Ok, all is set but it still the same. I also tried, like people said in the question I linked in my own question, to start the "SDK Manager" with Admin permissions but it doesn't work. It seems like I don't have permission but I'm an Admin on this PC..

Comment: Did you add SDK path into PATH?

Comment: Solved with a simple double click on the android.bat file that the SDK Manager didn't find. I don't know why but it didn't find ... Thank you the same !

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a network issue. When you open SDK manager , in the top left extreme you will find tools options,then choose options from a drop down.
[image: Screenshot below:]

**It gives you a proxy settings option.Enter the HTTP Proxy Server and port number.** It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I Solved It By setting permission to  full control for the current user on the android-sdk folder

Answer (score 0):

My solution (which is a clarification of what @amr-darweesh suggests):

- Go to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
- Select `Properties` for the `plugins` folder.
- Select the `Security` tab
- Click `Edit` (about half way down the window)
- Select `Users` in the top box
- Check `Full Control` is enabled in the bottom box
- Click `Apply`
- Click `OK`

Then, go to where the SDK is stored. When you run an SDK update, it will tell you this in the same line. Do the same thing for that folder.