# Android-SDK package installation error although Eclipse & SDK manager are run as Administrator on Vista

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, windows-vista

I am running Windows Vista and have an error in my Android application which is presented by Eclipse as:

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'
```

`CornBoyzTutorial Build Path Problem`. I go to the 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools` folder to see that there is no `support` folder. The beginning of Eclipse presented me with `This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools 17 or above. Current revision is 16. Please update your DDK Tools to the latest version.`

I have run Eclipse as Administrator and go to the Android SDK manager, to see that there is an update for the Rev.16 `Android SDK Tools` to Rev 19. I press for the installation of the packages and get the window message that the SDK Manager:failed to install, a folder failed to be moved, On Windows this typically means that a program is using that folder.. (eg anti-virus), ..close any running programs taht may be accessing the directory C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools`, When  ready ... try again.

The console message is:

```
[2012-05-06 13:35:20 - SDK Manager] Failed to rename directory C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools to C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01.
```

The Android SDK Manager Log message at the end is:

```
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 19
Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 19
Failed to rename directory C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools to C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

I have all anti-virus software turned off and no programs accessing this directory. I also ran the SDK manager from the Android folder directly as Administrator with the same error. I have also tried restarting Windows. Previous times when I update never showed this problem.

Comment: try to rename it manually to something different than "tools" or delete that folder. I think the installation process should complete.

Comment: @SatelliteSD & Chris Stratton, I renamed it (tools folder to toolsOLD), and then in Eclipse it gave me an error, and I tried to run the SDK manageger which is in the same directory as `tools` but it said that it could not find the .bat file.

Comment: I think a clean re-install of the SDK is going to be your fastest route to returning to working on your projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Android SDK manager (it's an application you can run by itself, Eclipse is only framing it) is itself located in the tools directory (clarification: I looked on the linux version, but would guess it's the same on windows).

You could try to copy it elsewhere and run that, or manually download and unzip the tools package, but it might be simplest to just re-install the latest SDK from scratch.

Comment: I used this approach and the comment by SatelliteSD to get it to work. I change the name of the folder manually, then changed it back again to the original name because the SDK manager wanted to change the paths if I remember correctly, but when I put everything back into its place the folder was renamed successfully.