# The following processes: -cmd.exe -java.exe are locking the following directory:

Tags: android, installation, android-sdk-2.3

I am installing 2.3.3 android API and i got this error:

```
Warning:
The following processes:
-cmd.exe
-java.exe
are locking the following directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
```

Any help??

Comment: Second time this has been seen today... you are running something, likely the sdk manager (program called "android") which is actually located in the tools folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470593/android-sdk-package-installation-error-although-eclipse-sdk-manager-are-run-as/10470884#10470884

Answer (score 25):

just go this dir:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\Android SDK\temp
```

and cut every thing was there then paste it in a new folder..

Run the Update again..

Comment: for hours i was trying the solution and finally got it working bcoz of this answer......

someone please accept the answer...

Comment: I extracted the .zip in temp and pasted all its contents into tools folder (after closing cmd) this sorted me out.

Comment: another possible location if you are using android studio is:
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. Then I downoaded [latest SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (only the SDK. no need to download android platforms).

There's a folder call "tools" in "android-sdk" folder. I replaced the previous "tools" folder with newly downoaded "tools" folder. So far it's working in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I did better went to sdk/temp and found out 
`tools_r22.6.3-windows.zip` which was downloaded but not installed 
i just extracted the zip and replaced tools in `\sdk\tools`

note : exit eclipse and sdk manager , **delete the old TOOLS folder** rater than replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is changing the name of the folder specified (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools). After changing the name of the folder i opened android studio. next i went into the tools folder that i renamed and ran the android.bat file. this opened up the manager and allowed me to install no problem. A new tools folder will be created and used im assuming its safe to delete the old one that was renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while the ddms was running (i was taking print screens from you phone). Exit and click Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this same problem and it has been solved.I configure the tools directory to the environment variable, This result can not rename the "tools" directory . solution: temporarily remove the environment variables inside, and then turn off the eclipse, and re-update.Hope it can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk 
Delete the folder "tools."
Extract the zip that has been downloaded in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r21.1-windows.zip to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. The folder inside this zip file is named "tools" and replaces the deleted folder.

It is the same as install the SDK Tools in the sdk manager.
I had this problem and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk and delete the temp folder. Rerun the SDK Manager to download the latest SDK's, it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it in this way: as said before, go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp and copy the content to a new folder. Extract the content of the zip file, which contains the new tools just downloaded, and copy the entire folder back to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. This worked for me.

Comment: hmm .. nothing new compared to an earlier answer, is there?

Answer (score 0):

Download sdk from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html .Copy tools folder from the downloaded sdk folder and replace existing tools dir in already existing sdk folder. This worked for me. I face this issue while updating sdk. Upon copying and pasting the tools will not give any issue as you will be replacing updated version of tools to your existing sdk. This is not the right way as you need to do it all the time when you need to update sdk. Better way is to copy tools dir in ur sdk and paste it with diff name like toolsDiplicate in this folder run android.bat file as administrator. Hope this helps. Any other way to resolve this issue or any reasons for which we face this issue please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by copying my \tools folder, naming the copy \toolsCopy. Then I ran android.bat from the \toolsCopy folder with Administrator privileges.

Running the SDK manager from \tools locked the renaming of the \tools directory, for obvious reasons. SMH

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your android-sdk folder.
2. Rename 'tools' folder like 'tools1' or 'toolss' or anything else
3. Open cmd with Administration and go to that new renamed tools1/toolss folder from cmd
   Ex-C:\Users\Eshad\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\toolss>android
4. Type 'android' for running the android.bat file
5. Now update

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows instead of doing all those tricky things I solved it by downloading the 'sdk only' installer.exe which you can get here -> http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

1)Scroll down and click on DOWNLOAD FOR OTHER PLATFORMS

2)You will see two tables ADT bundle and SDK tools only .In that 'Sdk Tools only' one you can get the installer.exe(dont click on the .zip download) ... Just download it and run it but remember if you have saved your android in some other drive which is not the default then you will have to specify the path to the android sdk folder when the installer asks you to specify the path.

This solved my problem quit well without any problem.Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

First go to folder where you have installed android SDK 
( default location : *C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk )
and rename the folder. ex : android-sdk-previousVersion

Then download the latest android SDK from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i

Install the downloaded SDK in the same location of the previous android sdk.

Your downloaded sdk will not contain any platforms or system images..

Open the previous android sdk's folder and copy these folders : add-ons, build-tools, docs, extras, platforms, platform-tools ,samples ,sources and system-images then paste these folders in you new sdk's directory. Overwrite the folders if same folders exist.

[image: Copy only the selected folders, changing other folders or files will result in failure]

Now you can delete the old android SDK folder.

Open the new android SDK and you will find all the platforms you had in the previous SDK.

Comment: If you can't find AppData folder, type it on the address bar, because it's hidden by default :)

Answer (score -1):

go to Temp folder and untick the Read-Only tick button and press

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the "temp" folder from the sdk folder and also the "temp" folder from the adt folder. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the the data from the `temp` folder which is inside the `sdk` folder is the best solution.  Other solutions may work.  You may have to try a lot of stuff....but ultimately, doing this will help you.

Comment: You have repeated what several other people have already said.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your android-sdk folder.
Rename 'tools' folder like 'tools1' or 'toolss' or anything else
Open cmd with Administration and go to that new renamed tools1/toolss folder from cmd Ex-C:\Users\Eshad\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\toolss>android
Type 'android' for running the android.bat file
Now update