# What is the right way to work with multiple AVD images for multiple API versions?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Recently I downloaded the Android SDK, but I ended up installing SDK-Platform for API-version 10 (Android 2.3.3), since that is the version I wanted to work with initially. However now I also need to work with Android 4.0.3, but SDK Manager continually fails to install the SDK-Platform for API-version 15, and thus doesn't install the corresponding system images either.

So I'm wondering, as to what is the right way to work with Android ICE, Jellybean (in future) and Gingerbread, on the emulators?

Comment: Assuming that you are using Windows: Have you started the SDK Manager as root to install the packages?

Comment: @nkr, not sure what you mean "as root" ? I am indeed on Windows 7, and my account has full Administrator rights.

Comment: Just right-click on the SDK Manager (e.g. in the startmenu) and click "Run as Administrator" (or similar). After that you should be able to install the desired packages.

Comment: Thanks @nkr. While I did find the 'Run as Administrator' option, and used it, the outcome was same, i.e. SDK Manager failed to install the latest SDK-Platform. Do I have to manually remove the installed API-10 SDK-Platform first ? Since it is the only working Platform, and my internet connectivity is poor, I am bit cautious in trying that out.

Comment: You can install as many platforms as you like. The only thing I could think of atm is to uninstall the whole SDK and reinstall it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like nkr said, you should try to run the sdk manager with full permession (UAC works better on windwos7 than on windows vista, but sometimes it needs a hand ;) ).

FYI: [previous question probably about the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components)

Comment: Agreed, that did help, and thanks @nkr. What was blocking was the fact that I have a lousy internet connection, s.t. the https download of the platform was breaking, which led to dependency failure for image etc., and thus nothing was getting installed. I moved to http based download, and installed everything one by one, and I could get a successful installation. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You should start Android SDK Manager and you should see new OS Platform.
You can download the OS image (es Gingerbread, ICS and so on).

Otherwise you can download the new version from www.android.com and re-install everything.

Once you have the OS image downloaded in your pc you can create different emulator using these images.
Hope this hep.

Answer (score 1):

Your build target should alway be latest platform (i.e. Jelly Bean API 16). Properties->Android->Build target

In your manifest you should define something like:

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Lint will tell you if your code uses something not available in previous versions.  You can test you code on any emulator to ensure correct functionality.