# Android SDK Manager fails to update SDK build tools revision 18.1.1

Tags: android, android-build, android-sdk-tools

Below is the command line result (the GUI one is very similar):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>android update sdk -u -a -t 3

.... licensing stuff

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
  URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\build-tools_r18.1.1-windows.zip (Access is denied)
  Done. Nothing was installed.
```

I didn't find anything on the web that could help. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using elevated permissions?

Comment: As per my comment, [run as admin seems to do the trick.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components?rq=1

Comment: Thank you - it worked.
I have Windows 8. Although my user is the admin, "Run as admin" made it... very strange...

Comment: I have created an actual answer rather than comment. Feel free to accept it as an answer :P. How was it strange?

Comment: it was strange that it need to be run as admin while the user is admin anyway. UAC?
This was the point why I had not even tried it this way (run as admin)...

Comment: Whilst a user can be an admin user it does not automatically grant admin privileges-this would be catastrophic in terms of installing unwanted programs, running unwanted scripts without a user knowing. Being an admin just means you don't need to enter the username/password of an admin user when trying to launch something with admin rights. But I digress, glad it worked for you.

Comment: thanx. it is very reasonable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

open the android Sdk folder right click on sdk manager run as administrator. select update/new install.

Comment: Thanx Raw... Already known. see above. Actually, I changed the Eclipse program properties to run as admin automatically and forgot about this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt as an administrator. Elevated permissions should resolve this issue.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Thanx to doydoy.
It works in two ways:
1) Running SDK manager as admin
2) Command line works when CMD window with admin priveleges is used (aka elevated permissions)