# URL not found error while downloading API platform tools for android

Tags: android, sdk

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I installed the Android SDK Manager, and am now trying to install a platform like the Android Dev website suggests. Once I clicked install I got an error stating that the Manager could not create a temp folder within the Android directory. So I created it. Now I'm getting this error:  Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 1 File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\temp\android-2.3_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied) There is also a little message under the progress bar that says "Done. Nothing was installed."  I'm running Windows 8, in case that's of any use.

Comment: Try to run the sdk manager as  administrator and install the platforms

Comment: yes.. dat worked out.. thanks man! @Giridharan

Comment: cool then i put it as answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK Manager Not Installing Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the android SDK folder and run SDK manager as the administrator and install the platforms