# Why can't I install android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to install android sdk but it gives the following error
URL not found:C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk (access denied)

It doesn't even ask me for password or any access dialog.What could be the problem?

Comment: This worked for me thanks. just ran as administrator.

Comment: ok I'm going to put my comment as an answer, please tick it so it is marked as answered and closed off so others can benefit from similar issues

Comment: See this similar question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components Pretty much need to run as **administrator** as per the accepted answer.