# Can't install new libraries and system images in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I couldn't install the SDKs and System Images for different Android versions in Android Studio. The package is downloaded but fails to install. With the new update of Android Studio 2.3 (or from previous versions, not sure) Google has made it mandatory to use SDK Manager provided in the IDE, there is no **'Launch Standalone SDK Manager'** anymore in the IDE. I have found an [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components) solution to this problem when there used to be a separate **'SDK Manager.exe'** file in the folder 'sdk' as shown below:

[image]

But I did a fresh installation of Android Studio 2.3 and there is no such file now:

[image]

On installing a new package or system image from SDK Manager in Android Studio I am getting following error every time:

[image]

Please help me as I am in the middle of development of a project which needs to be completed. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the failed file (https:dl.google.com/....google_m2repository_gms... .zip) directly (using some download manager if you experience network instability) and then unzip it and copy the content to `<android-sdk>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms`. In fact, you can download any part of android sdk manually and put it in the place it should be.

Comment: **"if you experience network instability"** I am not facing such issues, the package is downloaded completely but is not installing. The answer that I linked in my question says that since the SDK Manager has no right to write on disk, you need to launch the same with admin rights but in my case, there is no such file! :( @Merka

Comment: if it is downloaded completely, you can put it in its belonging folder manually. It will solve the issue.

Comment: The thing is it is downloaded through Android Studio and once the Android Studio fails to install it the whole SDK component or system image is gone. You cannot view it before it gets installed by the studio. @Merka