# I'm unable to install/download google play services in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-sdk-manager

> I'm unable to install/download google play services in android studio.

[This is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijCnv.png)

> When i press install it shows following error every time. I've working internet too.

[This is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14mDi.png)

how to solve this error?

Comment: Try [Run as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771911/5217712).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just put the text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error screenshot says that access is denied. You should try running Android studio as an administrator. You do this by right-clicking on android studio, then you click 'run as administrator', then click yes to allowing android studio to make changes to your computer (this step may require a password). Finally, you should retry installing google play services.

Comment: thnx thats worx