# Android Sdk Manager Failed to download any source list

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I'm trying to download platform-tools from Sdk Manager. but when I run :`C:\Users\tavak\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --list`
or any other commands related like \sdkmanager platform-tools
I get this error :

> Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
>   Warning: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml

The antivirus is disabled , and I'm running a proxy in whole device. I can successfully open the url in my browser. help me if possible !

Comment: you can find your solution on this link try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771895/android-sdk-manager-not-installing-components

Comment: I'm using cmd so there must'nt be any problem with running as administrator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using proxy, you need to specify your proxy settings:

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=127.0.0.1 --proxy_port=8118
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe the best solution for a person under blockade like me , is using faster proxys or I can download the sdk parts , manually. the needed ones include : 
platform-tools
builds 
emulator
platforms
...
It really bothers but no way !