# Gitlab CI/CD my pipeline faild, I cant downlaod source to build my APK

Tags: android, gitlab, continuous-integration, cd

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.2"
  release: "android"
  release_notes: "orange-apk-release"
  notify: false

# install the android sdk
before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-8092744_latest.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - mv android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools android-sdk-linux/latest
  - mkdir -p android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools
  - mv android-sdk-linux/latest android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools/
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

stages:
  - build
  - upload
assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/

upload-job:
  stage: upload
  before_script:
    - export INSTALL_DIR=$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - curl -Ls https://github.com/testappio/cli/releases/latest/download/install | bash
  script:
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ta-cli publish --api_token=$TESTAPPIO_API_TOKEN --app_id=$TESTAPPIO_APP_ID --release=$release  --apk=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk --release_notes=$release_notes --notify=$notify --source="Gitlab"
```

ERROR MSG :
echo y | android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
199 Warning: Failed to download any source lists

please guys any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this behind a proxy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154189/android-sdk-manager-failed-to-download-any-source-list

Comment: @BrandonKauffman Yes add these conf in gradle.properties

`org.gradle.daemon=true
systemProp.https.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts= localhost`