# error in installing android sdk starter package

Tags: android

I have downloaded eclipse, the android SDK starter package, and installed the "Developer Tools." Following the guide on developer.android.com exactly. After the developer tools have installed, and eclipse restarts I get two error messages:

1: "SDK Platform Tools component is missing! Please use the SDK Manager to install it."

So, I go in eclipse under Windows > Android SDK Manager and while trying to fetch the files it brings up the sdk manager log with the following:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Invalid argument: connect

Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason: Invalid argument: connect
```

Done loading packages.
Can anyone help me in resolving this problem?
Thanking you

Comment: Try http instead of https that's what Google suggests

Comment: I am new in android development.can you tell me how I can change http instead of https here

Answer (score 1):

- Goto Android SDK Manager 
  c://android-sdk-windows/  open
  SDK-Manager
- Click Settings - Will be
  asked for a proxy.
- If have one enter
  the IP address and the port number.
  If not turn off your firewall.
- Check
  "Force https://... "

Source [Android SDK Manager gives "Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml" error when selecting repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808167/android-sdk-manager-gives-failed-to-fetch-url-https-dl-ssl-google-com-android)