# Add Google Maps to Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I need help adding Google Maps to my Android app. I have followed the instructions on 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start, but I still get an error when running the app.

This my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.image.app" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".map" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBHPmNLCVvmVSCNTWYvhMUB65f1dwqSG5Y" />
</application>
<permission android:name="com.image.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.image.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<!-- Access Internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- Take picture -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- GET Latitude Longitude -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

This is my main class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

 public class map extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
}
 }
```

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: can u post the log cat details of the error or crash

Comment: I am getting the following error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Comment: post some relevant code and manifest

Comment: @Raghunandan please see the code mentioned in the post

Comment: have you referenced google play library project in your android map project? What's your api version?

Comment: @Raghunandan No i could not do that. This is the first time i am implementing a google map. Really am not clear about the procedure. Also I am using Eclipse 3.6.2 will that pose a problem ?

Comment: no you need to refer google play services library project in your android project

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you guide me how to add the Google play services library ?

Answer (score 8):

Go to windows. Android sdk manager. Scroll down choose google play services under extras and install

[image]

Copy the google-play services_lib library project to your workspace. The library project can be found under the following path.

```
     <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project .
```

Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse the     workspace  import the library project.

To check if its a library project. Right click got properties choose android. You see Is Library checked as below.

[image]

Next refer the library project in your android map project.

Right click on your android map project goto properties. choose android. click add browse the library project and click add and apply.

[image]

Make sure your api is 12 and above. If not you should use support fragment which requires support library.

Comment: My main problem is i cannot download the google play service lib

Comment: @meryld'souza why is that?

Comment: Whenever i open SDK Manager i get this error :Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41231. Check the solutions in the link. If nothing works reinstall eclipse and download fresh copy of android sdk.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808167/android-sdk-manager-gives-failed-to-fetch-url-https-dl-ssl-google-com-android. search on stackoverflow. lots of similar posts

Comment: @Raghunandan I followed the steps in your answer, when I tried to run the application it gave me this error message :" Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
GC overhead limit exceeded "