# Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com , failed to fetch different URLs

Tags: eclipse, android-sdk-tools

This is the error I am getting after starting SDK manager and also while updating or downloading packages(Download interrupted: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com). My ADT is also updated to Build: v22.6.2-1085508. I have read all the post regarding this and tried

1. Using https instead of http while using Help>install new software (getting error could               not find https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
2. No proxy.
3. Run SDK with admin privilege.
4. No firewall blocking .

I am not able to post the image because I am a new user , so i m copying the error and posting it , please don't mind .
This is type of error with many links like this ..

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Done loading packages.

Also I have read many answers on this site and other but nothing has helped so far.
Please help me .
Thank you

Comment: Check out [this answer][1] it might be useful for your case 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808167/android-sdk-manager-gives-failed-to-fetch-url-https-dl-ssl-google-com-android?rq=1#comment29450638_3810062

Comment: Not helping, i have seen this post.

Comment: Well i solved it . anyway thanks

Comment: Could you please kindly explain how did you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I solved this problem by running SDK manager as admin @ Windows 7

Comment: @ching My COMODO was the problem here , adding `adb.exe` to it's trusted program solved my problem.

Comment: I had the same issue and for me it was a firewall issue. I turned off the firewall and found my way around this issue. If you are trying from office or behind a corporate firewall then they might block some of these sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to add how I solved this problem if anyone comes here looking for an answer. 
Comodo firewall runs in background even if you disable the firewall and that causes problem with SDK . I had the same problem.
Steps I took to resolve my problem:

1. run comodo settings
2. defense+
3. list active processes
4. add adb.exe to trusted processes
5. restart server: run "adb kill-server" "adb start-server"

For Comodo 6.x

1. Open Comodo
2. Click Tasks Icon at right top
3. Click Advanced Tasks
4. Click Open Advanced Settings
5. Select Security Settings --> File Rating --> Trusted files from left panel
6. Click on the upward arrow icon at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

This might be because of Android SDK Manager not being able to connect to Google server. [This article](http://code2care.org/pages/download-interrupted-unknown-host-dl-ssl-google-com-android-sdk-manager/) helped me a lot:

`Tools` > `Options...` and check `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...`

Comment: very good link for both windows and apple.. what about us linux folks?

Comment: (Linux) figured it out... go to Android SDK Manager window.  Select Tools --> Options.  Select `[ ] Force https:// ... sources to be fetched using http://... ` (0r use the http proxy server of your choice...)

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting same error : Unknown Host Errors while installing ADT plugin in eclipse

Go to Setting -> Default setting -> select "Android SDK" from left side Panel. Select required components Which you want to install. - >Apply -> Ok.

Please let me know if still you are facing issue.

**Regard, 
Pappu.**